# Backbone Events: logging all events when they are triggered

Tags: backbone.js

I'm creating an events object using a bit of backbone and underscore as follows:

```
var appEvents = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

I'm then trying to create a function that will console.log all and any event triggered to this object, regardless of where, how or what listeners it has, but am kinda unsure how I'd do that. I'm still experimenting with Backbone.

I think using the listenTo method is the way to go... but again, not sure how I'd implement that.

Comment: Could you try to rephrase what's you're trying to do please? Because Backbone.Events is not really supposed to be used as an object. It only defines some method to extend all the other objects (Router, View, Collection, Model).

Comment: I'm sorry, think I didn't use the right wording. `appEvents` is working properly. I can do `appEvents.trigger('event')` just fine. What I'm trying to do is to somehow see in my console those events when they are triggered. So say I have an event called "openModal" being triggered when I click on a link, I'd like to have a `console.log` with the name "openModal" when I click that link that somehow works automatically when `appEvents.trigger` is called.

Answer (score 39):

You can just use Backbone's special `all` event:

```
appEvents.on("all", function(eventName){
    console.log(eventName + ' was triggered!');
});
```

Comment: See his comment, it's not listening, it's triggering.

Comment: This! Thank you! I knew it should be simple enough.

Comment: Enrique, please mark this answer as correct, based on your last comment.

Comment: and @EnriqueRamírezVélez was never heard from again

Answer (score 1):

```
var object = {};

_.extend(object, Backbone.Events);

object.on("alert:param1", function(msg) {
  alert("Сработало " + msg);
});


object.on("alert:param2", function(msg) {
  alert("Сработало " + msg);
});



object.on("all", function(eventName) {
  console.log(eventName);
});
object.trigger("alert:param2", "событие");
object.trigger("alert:param1", "событие");
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the trigger function then.

```
var trigger = appEvents.trigger;
appEvents.trigger = function(name) {
  console.log('Event', name, 'triggered.');
  trigger.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

But I still find the whole story weird (again, that's only my opinion).

Comment: Sorry I confused you (yet again). I used trigger as an example, but I was looking to see any changes on appEvents. @mVChr got it. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

"**add**" (model, collection, options) — when a model is added to a collection.

"**remove**" (model, collection, options) — when a model is removed from a collection.

"**update**" (collection, options) — single event triggered after any number of models have been added, removed or changed in a collection.

"**reset**" (collection, options) — when the collection's entire contents have been reset.

"**sort**" (collection, options) — when the collection has been re-sorted.

"**change**" (model, options) — when a model's attributes have changed.

"**changeId**" (model, previousId, options) — when the model's id has been updated.

"**change:[attribute]**" (model, value, options) — when a specific attribute has been updated.

"**destroy**" (model, collection, options) — when a model is destroyed.

"**request**" (model_or_collection, xhr, options) — when a model or collection has started a request to the server.

"**sync**" (model_or_collection, response, options) — when a model or collection has been successfully synced with the server.

"**error**" (model_or_collection, xhr, options) — when a model's or collection's request to the server has failed.

"**invalid**" (model, error, options) — when a model's validation fails on the client.

"**route:[name]**" (params) — Fired by the router when a specific route is matched.

"**route**" (route, params) — Fired by the router when any route has been matched.

"**route**" (router, route, params) — Fired by history when any route has been matched.

"**all**" — this special event fires for any triggered event, passing the event name as the first argument followed by all trigger arguments.